# Create an eclipse-like IDE in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ide, swt

I am trying to come up with a custom-made IDE to suit my needs. I tried Swing libraries to create a GUI but it doesn't look that good, plus I haven't figured out how to show something like a project explorer, watch window, etc.

Can someone please guide me how to create your own IDE in Java? Should I use SWT or swing framework?

Thanks

Comment: Rarely does an IDE use the base UI elements of its source language. You have to customize them to make them look the way you want.

Comment: Isn't java the father of all open source things? why don't you just grab the code off the eclipse repo and see how it's done?

Comment: I believe Eclipse provides APIs to create your own plug-ins.  Have you considered this route?

Comment: @sotiriosdelimanolis Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 are WPF-based.

Comment: I am learning now how to create a plugin, but was not sure whether I can impart the functionalities I need with it.

Comment: Getting and understanding the eclipse source code from: [link](http://git.eclipse.org/c//) does not seem to be straightforward. But I can surely try it if it would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirements are very loose. You can go with SWING, with NetBeans platform, with Eclipse Platform, with SWT. In most cases, in IDE you would expect:

1. Eclipse-like layouts supports. E.g. a number of "views" and "editors" that user can resize/rearrange - and his changes to be stored between restarts.
2. Project management functionality? Create project/files, track changes in files, do a build, manage metadata. Version control support is generally a must.
3. Have a specialized source editor with code assist, validations (e.g. compiler errors), shortcuts, etc.

If you need all of that - you should read about Eclipse plugins development. If you only need (1) then you may want to check Eclipse RCP documentation. If you don't need anything like that you may use SWING or SWT, it's more of a matter of taste.

Comment: I only need 1 for now. I'll start reading about eclipse RCP then. Thanks!